# how to remove a stamp from an image with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am working on a OCR project, and in the preprocessing, some RED stamps need to be removed, so that the text near the stamps could be detected. I try a lot of methods(like change the values of pixel, threshold in Red channel) but fail.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Python, C++, Java or what? Since you didn't state the OpenCV implementation you are using, I'm giving my answer in C++.

An option is to use the `HSV` color space to filter out the range of red values that defines the seal. My approach is to use the `CMYK` color space to filter everything except the black (or dark) text. It should do a pretty good job on printed media, which is your case.

```
    //read input image:
    std::string imageName = "C://opencvImages//seal.png";
    cv::Mat imageInput = cv::imread( imageName );
```

Now, perform the `CMYK` conversion. OpenCV does not support this operation out of the box, bear with me as I provide the helper function at the end of this post.

```
    //CMYK conversion:
    std::vector<cv::Mat> cmyk;
    cmyk = rgb2cmyk( imageInput );

    //This is the Black channel:
    cv::Mat blackChannel = cmyk[3].clone();
```

This is the image of the black channel; it is nice how everything that is not black (or dark) practically disappears!

[image]

Now, optionally, enhance the result applying **brightness and contrast adjustment**. Just try to separate the text from the background a little bit better; we want some defined pixel distributions to get a nice binary image.

```
    //Brightness and contrast adjustment:
    float alpha = 2.0;
    float beta = -50.0;
    contrastBrightnessAdjustment( blackChannel,  alpha, beta );
```

Again, OpenCV does not offer brightness and contrast adjustment out of the box; however, its implementation is very easy. Hold on a little bit, and let me show you the result of this operation:

[image]

Nice. Let's `Otsu-threshold` this bad boy to get a nice binary image containing the clean text:

```
    cv::threshold( blackChannel, binaryImage ,0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU );
```

This is what you get:

[image]

Now, the `RGB` to `CMYK` conversion function. I'm using the following implementation. The function receives an `RGB` image and returns a vector containing each of the `CMYK` channels

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> rgb2cmyk( cv::Mat& inputImage ){

    std::vector<cv::Mat> cmyk;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cmyk.push_back( cv::Mat( inputImage.size(), CV_8UC1 ) );
    }

    std::vector<cv::Mat> inputRGB;
    cv::split( inputImage, inputRGB );

     for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.rows; i++)
     {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.cols; j++)
            {

                float r = (int)inputRGB[2].at<uchar>(i, j) / 255.;
                float g = (int)inputRGB[1].at<uchar>(i, j) / 255.;
                float b = (int)inputRGB[0].at<uchar>(i, j) / 255.;
                float k = std::min(std::min(1-r, 1-g), 1-b);

                cmyk[0].at<uchar>(i, j) = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k) * 255.;
                cmyk[1].at<uchar>(i, j) = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k) * 255.;
                cmyk[2].at<uchar>(i, j) = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k) * 255.;
                cmyk[3].at<uchar>(i, j) = k * 255.;

            }
    }

    return cmyk;
}
```

And the `contrastBrightnessAdjustment` function is this, implemented using pointer arithmetic. The function receives a grayscale image and applies the linear transformation via the `alpha` and `beta` parameters:

```
void contrastBrightnessAdjustment( cv::Mat inputImage, float alpha, int beta ){

    cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it, end;
    for (it = inputImage.begin<cv::Vec3b>(), end = inputImage.end<cv::Vec3b>(); it != end; ++it) {
        uchar &pixel = (*it)[0];
        pixel = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha*pixel+beta);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can effect brightness contrast with cv2.normalize() or better skimage..exposure.rescale_intensity(). That will be much faster than a loop

Comment: @fmw42 If you use `Python`, sure, you can use those functions. The brightness/contrast adjustment is implemented via pointer arithmetic, so it should be alright and faster than a regular `C++` loop. The `CMYK` conversion can also be implemented using pointer arithmetic.